# How to change color of the record according to the value of it's attribute in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have **Entry** model with attribute **calories** and **date**. I also have **User** model with attribute **expected_calories**. When I display list of the entries it should be red if sum of calories per day is more than **expected_calories**, otherwise should be green.

**entries_controller.rb**

```
def index
@entries = Entry.where(user_id: current_user.id)
@user = current_user
if @user.role == 'admin'
  @entries = Entry.all
end
```

end

**index.html.slim**

```
        h1 Listing entries

    table.table
      thead
        tr
          th Date
          th Time
          th Content
          th Cal
          th User
          th
          th
          th

      tbody
        - if can? :manage, Entry
          - @entries.each do |entry|
            tr
              td = entry.date
              td = entry.time.strftime("%H:%M")
              td = entry.content
              td = entry.cal
              td = entry.user.role
              td = link_to 'Show', entry
              td = link_to 'Edit', edit_entry_path(entry)
              td = link_to 'Destroy', entry, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, method: :delete

    br

    = link_to 'New Entry', new_entry_path
```

Comment: Can you share what you have so far? (especially on the view part)

Comment: I've added. But still don't know how to make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very quick dirty way of doing this:

```
- if can? :manage, Entry
  - @entries.each do |entry|
    tr(style="background-color: #{entry.calories > current_user.expect_calories ? 'red' : 'green'})
```

I'd recommend you create some css classes. For example:

```
.expected-calories {
  background: green
}
.unexpected-calories {
  background: green
}
```

Then create a method in the `helpers/entries_helper`:

```
def expected_calories_class(user, entry)
  if user.expected_calories <= entry.calories
    'expected-calories'
  else
    'unexpected-calories'
  end
end
```

So your view would be more readable (and the logic would be testable):

```
- if can? :manage, Entry
  - @entries.each do |entry|
    tr(class=expected_calories_class(current_user, entry))
```

Comment: But i got

undefined method `<=' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  <=>
Extracted source (around line #3):
        
module EntriesHelper
  def expected_calories_class(user, entry)
    if user.expected_cal <= entry.cal
      'expected-calories'
    else
      'unexpected-calories'

Comment: is `current_user` set?

Comment: I use Devise, it should be in it.

Comment: In that case, it seems like either methods `expected_calories` or `calories` does not exist or are not returning a number